# Setting up for multiple fixed widths

Tags: mobile, media-queries, viewport, fixed-width

I'm having trouble setting up a site for multiple fixed widths with media queries on mobile.

If my design has a minimum fixed width of 400px this is wider than most smartphones.

With the meta tag setting:
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"

iOS will render the page at 400px and then scale it to fit the device screen. *Perfect*.

Android will render the page at 400px (*great*) but not scale it to fit (*damn*).

**How can i tell Android to automatically scale the page to fit?**

Attempted fixes:

1. I'd rather my users don't have to either zoom out or scroll
   horizontally. I know you can turn off user zooming in the meta and
   that makes the page scale automatically, but it's important that
   users can still zoom the page, thus, I can't use this solution.
2. Ideally I'd have the design as fluid, unfortunately a lot of the elements only work at 400px, thus this (for this project at least) is my minimum width.

Comment: Go for a DARL layout (Device Agnostic Responsive Design).  Essentially, you create break points with the media queries and then fluid layouts contract or stretch to fill the space at each break point.  Frigging with the viewport meta tag across all device types will give you a big headache.